# Is there a way to retrieve EAR from IBM Websphere Application Server Admin Console?

Tags: websphere, server-administration

just wondering if we can retrieve the EAR file of an application that was already installed on Websphere Application Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you navigate to: Applications > Enterprise Application you should have an option to export the EARs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also locate the unexpanded ear file and download it to your computer from the following directory.

```
      <profile_dir>/<profile_name>/config/cells/<cell_name>/applications/<applcation_name>
```

Comment: the server is at a remote location and all I have access to is the admin console. thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAS 8.5 or more, then the location is

> **Applications -> Application  Types -> Websphere Enterprise Applications**